# Add new column based on multiple column values using apply

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to add a new column to test_df which contains the value of column a or b depending on change_col and if change is True. The for loop below works, but is too slow. **How can I add the new column using apply** or similar?

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,1,2,3],
                    "b":["ant","ber","cas","dor"],
                    "change_col":["a","b","b","a"],
                    "change":[True,True,True,False]})

    a   b      change_col   change
0   1   ant        a       True
1   1   ber        b       True
2   2   cas        b       True
3   3   dor        a       False
```

the desired df:

```
    a   b     change_col    change  new_value
0   1   ant        a        True    1
1   1   ber        b        True    ber
2   2   cas        b        True    cas
3   3   dor        a        False   NaN
```

my for loop

```
new_value= []
for _ , row in test_df.iterrows():
    if row["change"] is True:
        new_value +=[row[row["change_column"]]]
    else:
        new_value += [np.NaN]
test_df["new_value"] = new_value
```

I'm using pandas 0.24.2 on python 3.7.

Comment: Disagree with the duplicate, this is not plain lookup. See my comment under Vaishali's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DataFrame.lookup][1],

```
test_df['new_val'] = test_df.lookup(test_df.index, test_df['change_col'])

    a   b   change_col  change  new_val
0   1   ant a           True    1
1   1   ber b           True    ber
2   2   cas b           True    cas
3   3   dor a           False   3
```

Edit: To account for the change column, use condition

```
test_df['new_val'] = np.where(test_df['change'], test_df.lookup(test_df.index, test_df['change_col']), np.nan)

    a   b   change_col  change  new_val
0   1   ant a           True    1
1   1   ber b           True    ber
2   2   cas b           True    cas
3   3   dor a           False   NaN
```

Comment: Like this one, you just miss one condition, this should work: `np.where(test_df['change'], test_df.lookup(test_df.index, test_df['change_col']), np.NaN)`

Comment: @Erfan, yeah I didn't see the change condition, thanks

Comment: Also works for multiple columns!

Answer (score 3):

Since you have multiple conditions, we can use `np.select` here to define our conditions and based on those conditions we choose our values:

```
conditions = [
    test_df['change_col'].eq('a') & test_df['change'].eq(True),
    test_df['change_col'].eq('b') & test_df['change'].eq(True)
]

test_df['new_value'] = np.select(conditions, choicelist=[test_df['a'], test_df['b']], default=np.NaN)
```

**Output**

```
   a    b change_col  change new_value
0  1  ant          a    True         1
1  1  ber          b    True       ber
2  2  cas          b    True       cas
3  3  dor          a   False       NaN
```

Comment: select has default, nice :D

Comment: Yes :), plus I like to program explicity `eq(True)` since it can be confusing for beginners to understand that in combination with a vectorized solution such as `np.select` @Adam.Er8

Answer (score 0):

here's a solution using [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test_df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 1, 2, 3],
                        "b": ["ant", "ber", "cas", "dor"],
                        "change_col": ["a", "b", "b", "a"],
                        "change": [True, True, True, False]})

change_a = ((test_df['change']) & (test_df['change_col'] == 'a'))
change_b = ((test_df['change']) & (test_df['change_col'] == 'b'))
dont_change = ~test_df['change']

conditions = [change_a, change_b, dont_change]
choices = [test_df['a'], test_df['b'], np.nan]

test_df["new_value"] = np.select(conditions, choices)

print(test_df)
```

Output:

```
   a    b  change change_col new_value
0  1  ant    True          a         1
1  1  ber    True          b       ber
2  2  cas    True          b       cas
3  3  dor   False          a       NaN
```